# Difference between thread joinable and detached?

Tags: c++, multithreading

What exactly would be the difference between a joinable thread and a detached thread ??

Answer (score 5):

"Joinable" means that the thread's creator is still responsible for the thread's resources; you must join the thread at some point to wait for the thread to finish (if it hasn't already) and clean up those resources.

"Detached" means that the thread has been made responsible for its own resources, and must not be joined. Do this if you want to let the thread run independently and forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

One can be joined up at a later stage (i.e. get exit status). The other can carry on its merry way and another thread is unable to find out what it has been up to